# react-router Switch is stopping the state to pass down to the child components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I have written a sample code for learning `react-redux`. The `Provider` I have written is successfully passing down the store, but the `react-router-dom`'s `Switch` is stopping the store to go down further below. Below is the index.js file(the entry point of application)

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={PhotoGrid} />
          <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </App>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
```

The idea behind above code is: `App` is a component which implements the redux `connect` method and then calls the `Main` component which is the parent to all the components. The `Main` is kind of header, under which the paragraph(`PhotoGrid`, `Single`) will change based on the URL. `Main` is fix.

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          <Link to="/">Reduxtagram</Link>
        </h1>
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone please give any idea, why state is being blocked by `Switch`.
[image: store state is visible here]
[image: store state is not visible here]

Comment: What do you mean "blocked" by the `Switch`? You can't use `connect` on e.g. `PhotoGrid` which is lower than `Switch`?

Comment: Hi Tholle, blocked means - I am passing the `store` to all the child components, and if you see the images, all the `actions`(addComment, increment, removeComment) are coming up to  the first `Switch` and then the actions are not getting passed down to child components

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/location-object
"the location prop passed to <Route> will be overridden by the one used by the <Switch>"
could this be the reason?